# Is separation required around a 12V AC input, if its surrounded by 3.3v and logic level voltages?

Tags: ac, 12v

I personally think it does, but my colleague thinks differently, I would seriously appreciate a proper opinion on this!

Comment: What are you afraid of? Electric arcs? Electromagnetic interferences? Most likely none of those would be a problem. Something else, then?

Comment: the fact that its near 3.3v and 1v type rails? is it fine being literally right next to all that.

Comment: Usually, yes, it's perfectly fine. That's why I ask: what are you afraid of? So that answers can be more relevant to your fears/specific case.

Comment: there is a Wifi chip on the board, I am just afraid of something bad happening from the 12v input, it has to go literally all over the board past all kinds of different important logic level components, like electro magnetic interference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- voltage E field pF/cm crosstalk depends on voltage transients Z(f), which is low at line f.
- current H field crosstalk depends on dI/dt current spikes and nH coupling an Zin
- layout depends on EMI immunity specs.  if you define, (using concepts above) then there is no guessing.

.

- supply noise, signal noise allowed ,  radiated and conducted source, level, distance
- experience makes the choices easier using guard ground tracks and Common Mode Rejection (f) estimations, then test and verify when built.

In terms of lightning isolation, from line to secondary to DC, analyze your need for a line filter and MOV.  "Good" iron core transformers with 20:1 voltage ratio at line frequencies often attenuate 60dB or 10kV spike to 10V secondary from coupling factors. Ferrite is worse, due lower losses and high f coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding electric arcing, at these voltage levels, you have nothing to fear.

Regarding electromagnetic interferences, the voltage is not relevant. High voltage doesn't generate more EMI. What generates EMI is quickly varying signals. Because your 12V is supposed to be steady, it isn't supposed to cause any EMI. What could eventually be a problem, however, is if the 12V picks up some interferences from outside the case (e.g. in the wire between the wall wart and your device), or if the 12V is really badly filtered at the supply. It could then radiate EMI to the rest of your circuit. In this case, rather than isolating this track from the rest of the circuit, you'd better filter it at the entry of the case, near the connector, using a ferrite and capacitor.